# vb.net, sqlexpress, table does not exist

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have sqlexpress installed, am able to connect to the server but says the table does not exits.

Here is the code:

```vb
Dim myConn As SqlConnection
        myConn = New SqlConnection("Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        Dim mySQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblStores"
        Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter(mySQL, myConn)
        Dim MyDS As New DataSet()
        myConn.Open()
        myDA.Fill(MyDS)
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = MyDS.Tables(0)
        myConn.Close()
```

[image: screen shot of my server]

Any ideas of why I can't connect to the table says it doesn't exist

Comment: Why are you creating user objects in `master`? Also, you are clearly not connected to the same instance. The Connection string says `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` and the image says `SKIP` (no named instance)

Comment: first time using it and when I installed the server that is the connection string it gave me.

Comment: What is "it"? What gave you that connection string? That doesn't change my point; in SSMS you are connected to a instance on the host `SKIP` using the default instance name (`MSSQLSERVER`), and in the code you are connecting to an instance called `SQLEXPRESS` on the localhost. Even if `SKIP` and `localhost` are the same host, `SQLEXPRESS` <> `MSSQLSERVER`; those are 2 different instances.

Comment: thanks for the help .... firgured it out with your info.  I am now connected to the SQLEXPRESS and created a new DB shopping ... new connection string: myConn = New SqlConnection("Server=SKIP\SQLEXPRESS;Database=shopping;Trusted_Connection=True;") ... it now populates ... ty so much

Answer (score 0):

First of all, wrong ServerName. And after that please create your own DB, don't use master DB.